# How to set a HTML, CSS and Javascript mode in CodeMirror editor? I want to combine all in one editor

Tags: javascript, html, css, codemirror

How to set an HTML, CSS, and JavaScript mode in CodeMirror editor? I want to combine all in one editor.

Thank You...

```
<script>
  var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("demotext"), {
    lineNumbers: true,
    styleActiveLine: true,
    mode: "text/html",
    readOnly: 'nocursor',
    mode: "javascript",
    matchBrackets: true
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`htmlmixed`](https://codemirror.net/mode/htmlmixed/index.html) mode. This mode includes CSS and Javascript.